# The body of the closure is so long, how to make it shorter

Tags: swift, closures

The body of the closure is so long, how to make it shorter

```
let clourse = { (repeatMode: AnimRepeatIntType) -> Bool in
        switch repeatMode {
        case .restart:
            return false
        case .reverse:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
    anim?.autoreverses = clourse((item?.repeatMode)!)
```

The body of the closure is so long, how to make it shorter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the whole `switch` statement with:

```
return repeatMode == .reverse
```

But there seems to be little reason for the closure.

You can change:

```
anim?.autoreverses = clourse((item?.repeatMode)!)
```

to:

```
anim?.autoreverses = item?.repeatMode! == .reverse
```

Though I would take steps to avoid those `!` in your code.